# "Link", "Alias" or "Create shortcut" in WP Media Library

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, files

[image]

### Introduction

Here you can see a folder structure within a media library (Wordpress). Now, I want to make it very userfriendly to make it possible, that a file can be in multiple folders. The user should know, that the files are **not directly "copied"** in the file system.

Instead, it should work like the **Windows Explorer**: There is one file fixed to a folder and you can create a shortcut through the context menu.

### Possible approachs:

- "Hold any key to create a file shortcut" -> "Link 1 file" (Window Explorer)
- "Hold any key to link the files" -> "Link 1 file" (Link = Linux?)
- "Hold any key to create a file alias" -> "Link 1 file" (MAC)

Do you know some better solutions?

[image]

After the shortcut is created, the file is still in the "Wup" folder, and the "Test" folder contains this shortcut.

Comment: So you just want to make the user aware that the file is not being copied, or you want to differentiate between copying (just dragging) and linking (with a key like the 3 approaches you proposed)?

Comment: Yes, You are right.

Comment: Why not 'categorize' or 'tag' the images. Instead of folders the user would then be able to sort images by tag groups but also have the ability to 'view all' if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to allow users to create a symlink to the image so it can be accessed through different URLS. If you go to domain.com/images/image.jpg and domain/images/folder/symlink.jpg it will show the same image. It's a very uncommon practice to allow your users to do this, but it's certainly possible. If you want to use a shortcut, then you can mimic the behaviour that Windows uses. Allow them to create a shortcut in the folder through the context menu. Then they can move the shortcut to the correct folder. In my opinion this is easiest way to do a shortcut, because the users are already familiar with this behaviour.

Another option is creating a button or context menu where the user can select the symlink destination in a file tree structure. This give them an overview of where they can put the image.

[image: Example of a file tree structure]